# Mapping XMLs from multiple XML schemas to one Class type

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf

I've input xmls from multiple sources each following its own schema. These keep increasing over time.
I've a target class type. All these XML should be transformed to the object of the target class type.

I'm looking for a solution which allows me to configure any XML, convert it to target class. So generic the data could be from attributes, values, etc. and the xml can have multiple namespaces.
I should be able to map (define a map) any attr/ node values to properties of the target class type. save these mappings and use the mapping when a XML comes with similar schema.

Language to use: C#, .net framework 4.0

examples:

input:
xml samples:

`<data>
    <human>
        <name>myName</name>
    </human>
</data>`

`<xmldata>
    <a:person name="yourName" >
    </a:person>
</xmldata>`

target class :

`Person {
    string name;
}`

output:

for first xml
mapping: `Person.name = "//human/name/text()"`

for second xml
mapping: `Person.name = "//a:person/@name"`

result of both:
`Person { name = "yourName" }`

Comment: Did you find a proper solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For such case I would use LINQ TO XML
For example:

```
public static MyObject Create(XElement e)
    {
        var obj = Create();

        obj.A= e.Element("A").Value;
        obj.B= e.Attribute("B").Value;           


        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: I actually want to generate a mapper/transformer for a xml to generate object. These mappers should be processed by a single handler then which gives me the target object.

Comment: **Mapper1**

`map1.IdMapper= '//human/id/text()"
map1.NameMapper = "//human/name/text()"`



**Mapper2**
`map2.IdMapper= '//a:person/@id"
map2.NameMapper = "//a:person/@name"`



and then a transformer uses these mappers with xpaths.

`targetObject = getObject(map1, xml1)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a sql table to have XPath value of each parameter. One row from this table will have xpaths of one source. we can have a primary key will be the source id and remaining columns will have xpaths for each parameter needed from the input xml.

Now, everytime you need to onboard a new source just have a sql changescript to configure for the that source or develop an UI to let the user to select from sample xml from source and populate the table.

To start with, its good idea to go with changescript, and later can be thought of developing an UI for it, thats again your choice of preference.

Once you have source config in place in table row, everytime you have to process the xml from a source, read his corresponding config entry from table and process the source xml accordingly.